# How to remove only A and B markers in a route but not waypoint marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Im using

```
setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );
```

to remove markers in a route.

But it removers all markers in that route. I want waypoint markers to be viewed in that route. So how can i remove only 'A' and 'B' markers from a route????

Answer (score 0):

Use `suppressMarkers: true` to suppress all the markers, then add back the waypoint markers.  Here is an example that recreates everything:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypointsE.html